# Paradox of two plates which are supposed to be equipotential

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, dielectric

Let's have large two conductor plate of area $A$  and are filled with two adjacent dielectrics of the same size $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon{2}$. The charge of the condensers are fixed by $Q$. Analyzing using Gauss Law, the displacement field is the same in the two media, so the electric field is different for each material. So if I measured the potential difference in the plates for each media, it's going to be different. But the conductor is an equipotential, so how can it be possible?

[image]

Comment: I assume that the plates are big enough

Comment: Do you have the same problem with two different capacitors in parallel? Is the same situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: **the potential won't be different**.

The misunderstanding is that in order to think this way you are assuming the charge Q will be uniformely distributed across each plate. This is what will happen:

- Since the total charges are fixed, when inserting the dielectrics, the charge densities will be: $\sigma_1 = \dfrac{Q_1}{A/2}$ and $\sigma_2 = \dfrac{Q-Q_1}{A/2}$.
- The displacement fields inside the capacitor will be: $D_1 = \sigma_1$ and $D_2 = \sigma_2$.
- The electric field is uniform by hipothesis in the electrostatic regime, because otherwise charge would flow until electrostatic regime is reached: $E_1 = E_2 = \frac{\sigma_1}{\epsilon_1} = \frac{\sigma_2}{\epsilon_2}$
- There is a charge imbalance in both sides. Solving the system:
  $$\frac{Q_1}{\epsilon_1} = \frac{Q-Q_1}{\epsilon_2} \rightarrow Q_1 = \dfrac{Q}{1+\epsilon_2/\epsilon_1}$$
- The charge-density imbalance is: $\sigma_1 = \dfrac{Q}{({1+\epsilon_2/\epsilon_1})(A/2)}$ and $\sigma_2 = \dfrac{Q}{({1+\epsilon_1/\epsilon_2})(A/2)}$.

#### Note added:

If you compute the polarization charge in each dielectric, you will see the total charge density (metal + polarization) remain uniform.

Comment: Thank you. Just a question. At the interface since the tangential component of the displacement field must be continous, but since is constant in both sides, that would mean that the displacement field must be the same so that contradicts that D is different in both sides. Can you help me find what is wrong with my statement?

Comment: I think it may be due to the fact that the tangential continuity comes from the no curl of the field. But in the interface I think that the curl of the displacement field is not zero. Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't specify the field's directions.

- All tangencial components vanish if we don't consider the fringing effect on the fields, which I think is a reasonable assumption if you don't care about precision near the interface bt the two dielectrics. Both D and E are normal to the metal plates

- The discontinuity in D (normal component) from one side of the metal to the other is due to the free charge density acumulated.

Comment: - The discontinuity in D tangencial component to interface bt dielectrics, from one dielectric to the other, is a approximation due to neglecting the fringing effect. However I am not sure how to explain this better. Did I answer your question?